# find $f(n)$ for recurrence $T(n)=2T(\dfrac{n}{2})+\mathcal{O}(n\log{n})=\Theta(f(n))$

Tags: time-complexity, algorithm-analysis, asymptotics, recurrence-relation, master-theorem

> We have recurrence $T(n)=2T(\dfrac{n}{2})+\mathcal{O}(n\log{n})$ and
> assume $T(1)$ is a constant. Find asymptotically tight bounds
> $\Theta(f(n))$ for $T(n)$.

There's something that confuses me. We know $\{n\log{n}, n, \sqrt{n}\}\subset \mathcal{O}(n\log{n})$. So with Master Theorem applied:

- if $T(n)=2T(\dfrac{n}{2})+n\log{n}$, then $T(n)=\Theta(n\log^2{n})$
- if $T(n)=2T(\dfrac{n}{2})+n$, then $T(n)=\Theta(n\log{n})$
- if $T(n)=2T(\dfrac{n}{2})+\sqrt{n}$, then $T(n)=\Theta(\sqrt{n})$

If its asymptotically tight bounds varies, then how can we provide a asymptotically tight bounds for $T(n)=2T(\dfrac{n}{2})+\mathcal{O}(n\log{n})$? If we can, how? Can we prove it using induction?

Comment: For your third case, how are you getting $\Theta(\sqrt{n})$ from the master theorem?
I would think that a recurrence relation with the first term $2T(n/2)$ will never be smaller than $\Theta(n)$, even if the second term is zero.

Comment: Cross-posted: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/162604/755, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4793413/14578.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right, you can't find a tight bound with those hypotheses.

I think you should interpret the question as:

> find $f(n)$ for recurrence $T(n)=2T(\dfrac{n}{2})+\Theta(n\log{n})=\Theta(f(n))$

In this case, your first relation gives the right answer ($f(n) = n(\log n)^2$).

Also, as noted in the comment, your third relation is wrong, it should be $\Theta(n)$, not $\Theta(\sqrt{n})$.